# Pass a value to my function in php

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have a list of products in a table extracted from my DB.
Each product have a field with ALIQUOTA (= VAT, Tax).
I want to have the possibility to modify the aliquote value assigned to single products.

I did a drop menu next to the actual aliquote that contains all the allowed value from an **aliquote** table of my database. (that values are 0.00, 4.00, 10.00, 20.00).
Once selected, that value will be inserted in a readonly input text field with id "aliquota_XXX" (where XXX is the id that correspond to the product).
Then i want to save that value pressing the button **CONFIRM VAT** that activate the function **save_modify** (this function already exists in the project).
This is the code:

```
<select class="piccolo elemento_modulo_obbligatorio" id="aliquota_dropdown_<?php echo $row['rid']; ?>" name="aliquota_dropdown">
<?php 
$aliquote = "SELECT aliquota,id AS aid FROM aliquote ORDER BY aliquota ASC";
$result_aliquote = mysql_query($aliquote) or die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
while ($row_aliquote = mysql_fetch_array($result_aliquote)) {
echo '<option onclick=\'';
?>

$("#aliquota<?php echo $row['rid']; ?>").val("<?php echo $row_aliquote['aliquota']; ?>");

<?php
echo ';\' value="' . $row_aliquote['aid'] . '">' . $row_aliquote['aliquota'] . '</option>';
}
?>

</select>

<input autocomplete="off" type="text" class="class12" id="aliquota<?php echo $row['rid']; ?>" name="aliquota" readonly="readonly" value="" />
<input type="button" onclick="save_modify(&quot;aliquota&quot;,document.getElementById('aliquota_<?php echo $row['rid']; ?>').value,<?php echo number_format($row['aliquota'],2,".",","); ?>);" value="CONFIRM VAT" />
```

The function **save_modify** is that:

```
function save_modify(cosa, valore_nuovo, valore_vecchio) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "ajax_salva_modifica_valore.php",
        data: "id_documento=" + <? php echo $_GET['id_documento']; ?> +"&cosa=" + cosa + "&id=" + id + "&valore_nuovo=" + valore_nuovo + "&valore_vecchio=" + valore_vecchio,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            $("#sezione_messaggi").html("Succesfully modified!");
        },
        beforeSend: function() {
            $("#sezione_loading").html("<img src='../images/ajax-loader.gif' />");
        },
        complete: function() {
            $("#sezione_loading").html("");
            post_modifica(id);
            carica_righe();
        }
    });
}
```

And the part of **ajax_salva_modifica_valore.php** that interest that is:

```
<?php
session_start();
$cosa = $_GET['cosa'];
$array_id = split("_",$id);
$id_riga = $array_id[1];


$valore_nuovo = $_GET['valore_nuovo'];
$valore_vecchio = $_GET['valore_vecchio'];

if($cosa == "aliquota") {
    $modifica = "UPDATE righe_documenti
                 SET aliquota = '" . $valore_nuovo . "'
                 WHERE id = " . $id_riga;
    $result = mysql_query($modifica) or die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error()); 
}
?>
```

I don't know where is the problem, because the parameter passed to the function are correct, but the modify it's not applied...

Someone can help me to fix it or try another solution?

The **save_modify** and **ajax_salva_modifica_valore.php** are not made by me, so i suppose that them are correct (and they works for the edit of other products information...)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that `number_format()` formats number as a string and should be enclosed in double quotes (`&quot;`) in your case.

```
<input type="button" onclick="save_modify(&quot;aliquota&quot;,this.id,$(&quot;#aliquota<?php echo $row['rid']; ?>&quot;).val(),&quot;<?php echo number_format($row['aliquota'],2,",","."); ?>&quot;);" value="CONFIRM ALIQUOTA" />
```

However by looking at the rest of your code, it seems you don't need `number_format()` at all:

```
<input type="button" onclick="save_modify(&quot;aliquota&quot;,this.id,$(&quot;#aliquota<?php echo $row['rid']; ?>&quot;).val(),<?php echo $row['aliquota']; ?>);" value="CONFIRM ALIQUOTA" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but no, it's not that the problem.
I made some test and the parameter of save_modify that have problem is the 3rd:
$(&quot;#aliquota<?php echo $row['rid']; ?>&quot;).val()

I replaced it with:
document.getElementById('aliquota_<?php echo $row['rid']; ?>').value

And now the parameter is passed... But the function don't do his job yet...